# Windsor & NServiceBus

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

I'm going to use NServiceBus and I'd like to use Windsor as "Builder"

I read a lot of posts in the past about bugs & incompatiblity concerning handler creation vs lifestyle.

I also read about fixing and new releases.

I'd like to be advised about the status of the integration.

Which are the builds (NServiceBus / Windsor) that are going along well?

Is http://nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.CastleWindsor/3.3.5 a good and stable start?

Is there any contrib sample to use those 2 guys within a MVC3 project?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, http://nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.CastleWindsor/3.3.5 is the latest stable version of Windsor + NServiceBus integration, this package was tested against Castle.Windsor v3.0.0.4001

Using NServiceBus + Windsor in a MVC3 project should be pretty easy, see [this sample](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/AsyncPagesMVC3) as a starting point.
All you should need to do is reference the [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/NServiceBus.CastleWindsor/3.3.5) and change in the `Global.asax.cs` the `Application_Start()` to use the Windsor container, for example:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    // NServiceBus configuration
    Configure.WithWeb()
        .CastleWindsorBuilder()
        .ForMvc()
        .JsonSerializer()
        .Log4Net()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
        .UnicastBus()
            .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
}
```

Comment: My main concern is lifestyle for handlers. I assume they have to be Transient, but what about releasing? I read in the past some issue on this topic. Do I really need to disable Tracking object in windsor to use it w/ Nservicebus or this issue has been solved in the latest releases?

Comment: No, that has been all fixed in v3